# How long should I keep driver verifier running and should I do anything on my pc?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, microsoft-driver-verifier

I have another post up at winten forums where people are helping me with BSODs on my gaming pc whenever I play games and they suggested I run driver verifier and send them two more bsod minidump files. My question is once I enable driver verifier how long should I wait to disable it? If I don't get a bsod within the first 1 hour of it running should I turn it off and assume my drivers are not the problem since when playing games I always get the bsod within the first 15 minutes. Should I just let my computer sit while driver verifier is enabled or should I play a game on it to try and get that same blue screen again (I have it enabled now and rebooted my computer)?

One more questions, they recommend that I turn off auto restart when I get a bsod, but if I do get a bsod with auto restart disabled how would I boot up again during a bsod? would I just press and hold the power button on the pc?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: You would restart your computer. But I personally wouldn't run driver verifier at all, it's not required, everything can be determine from dmp files

Comment: @Ramhound no, for such crashes you have to activate driver verifier otherwise you don't get the real cause.

Comment: @Ramhound I forgot to add a link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I only realized after I looked it up, I was on my phone initially, was the tool a MS debugging tool.

Comment: is your question answered or do you need more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable it again, after you got new crashes and provided the dmp files. DriverVerifier [slows down Windows a lot (causes DPC issues)](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/?p=1077578).